# Regex modifying text

Tags: ruby, regex

Can I concatenate text to other text using regex?

I have a string consisting of:

```
"bird dog fish"
```

I would like to output:

```
"bird catdog fish"
```

Would I use `gsub` to accomplish this? I'm getting confused because, if I match "dog" using `gsub`, I would have to replace "dog" with "catdog" instead of just adding "cat" to the front of it.  How can I just add some text to a specific match?  Do I have to use scan or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's wrong with doing replacement?

```
>>> "bird dog fish".gsub(/(dog)/, 'cat\1')
=> "bird catdog fish"
```

The `\1` is a reference to the `(dog)` captured group. Of course, `(dog)` could be any valid regex, so this example could easily be used in more complex situations.

You can have more than one capturing group, if you need to.

```
>>> "bird dog fish".gsub(/(dog)(.*)(sh)/, 'cat\1\3\2')
=> "bird catdogsh fi"
```

Ruby 1.9 introduced *named capture groups*:

```
>>> "bird dog fish".gsub(/(?<mydog>dog)/, 'cat\kmydog')
=> "bird catdog fish"
```

This is Ruby. There's **always** many ways to do it. More can be found in the standard documentation.

Comment: @Jack: It's a reference to a captured group. The parens around `dog` in the Regex specify that it should be "captured" for use in the output.

Comment: Ahh.  Can you do stuff like \2 or \3?  If so what would that do?